# how to check if cache is working

Tags: disk, swap, cache

is there a way to check if disk cache is working on a regular sata disk?

i see "asking for disk cache failed" error messages, but discovered my laptop has a 1gb solid state drive without a partition. i saw it in disk utility.
so if i can confirm that the hdd has a working cache then my next goal will be to setup ubuntu to use the solid state for swap instead of the swap area on the hdd.

Comment: Copying a file with a size smaller than your HDD cache should be "instantaneous" (very fast, depends on the memory to sata transfer rate). Sending a file that's larger will block (go as slow as the HDD write) once the cache is full.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to copy a file on the disk and then you should type

```
free -m
```

in your terminal. You will be able to see the amount of used cache space and the amount of free cache space.

[Page](https://serverfault.com/questions/237903/how-do-i-see-if-my-disk-cache-is-disabled-on-linux) with info.

Comment: confirmed cache is working, so error must be coming from solid state, which is /dev/zram0 Now how do I tell Ubuntu to use /dev/zram0 for swap?

Comment: That should be posted in another question. =)